# Information leaks out of encrypted file system

Tags: files, security, encryption, directory-structure

If I only encrypt the home directory, what are some common ways for information to leak out to the unencrypted part of the file system? Aside from the obvious problems like

- swap space
- files in `/tmp`

are there any *common* Linux programs leaking information (those which are nearly certainly part of a normal installation)?

For example something like `locate`: it leaks all file names to `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db` and is even part of a *minimal* Debian or Arch Linux installation.

Comment: How leaky do you want your leakage? `at`'s script files will contain the environment, but they're only readable to the user and root.

Comment: Well another obvious place would be in log files located in `/var/log` but you are going to have to specify what you mean by "information" in this context.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz: 'leak' means that parts of files or file names which are in `/home/user` become readable for somebody who took the disk out of the computer.

Comment: @M_dk: 'information' = parts of files or file names which are in the encrypted file system mounted to `/home/user`.

Comment: swap space can be encrypted (OpenBSD has done this for over a decade now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from home directories, there are three directory hierarchies with writable data: `/etc`, `/tmp` and `/var`.

- `/etc` contains system configuration files, most of which are typically not sensitive. But there can be sensitive data there, e.g. wifi passwords.
- `/tmp` can potentially contain sensitive data; just about any program might put temporary files there. This is easily dealt with by making it an in-memory filesystem (`tmpfs`). This way, if its content ever ends up on disk, it'll be in swap, which has to be encrypted if you care about encrypting anything.
- `/var` has many subdirectories. In particular:

  - `/var/tmp` is like `/tmp`, but it's supposed to be on-disk. Few programs write there, but when it's used at all, it's usually for large files. It's difficult to predict who's going to need it, so it should be encrypted.
  - `/var/mail` (or `/var/spool/mail`) may end up containing sensitive data, or it may not. It depends how you use local mail and whether error messages from cron job may contain sensitive data.
  - `/var/spool/cups` or `/var/spool/lp` (or a few other variations) contain temporary files during printing. If you ever print confidential documents, this should be encrypted as well.
  - Other directories in `/var/spool` may contain sensitive data, such as outgoing emails.
  - Sensitive information can end up in system logs in `/var/log`.
  - As you noted, if you have sensitive file names, they may end up in `/var/cache/locate` or `/var/lib/mlocate` or variations on that theme.

If you want peace of mind, just encrypt everything except `/boot`. Nowadays most computers are powerful enough that the cost of encryption on the CPU is negligible, and most distributions support whole-disk encryption easily.